# Is this TF training curve overfitting or underfitting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

In the case of overfitting, to my knowledge the `val_loss` has to soar as opposed to the `train_loss`.
But how about the case below (`val_loss` remains low)? Is this model underfitting horribly? Or is it some completely different case?
Previously my models would overfit badly so I added the dropout of 0.3 (4 CuDNNGRU layers with 64 neurons and one Dense layer and batchsize of 64), so should I reduce the dropout?

[image: train_loss vs. validation_loss]

Comment: It helps enormously (for clarity, indexing, findability from search engines) if you concisely **explain in words** your case: "`val_loss` remains low".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is neither overfitting nor underfitting. Some people refer to it as *[Unknown fit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187335/validation-error-less-than-training-error)*. Validation << training loss happens when you apply regularization (L1, L2, Dropout, ...) in keras because they are applied to training only and not on testing (validating). So it makes sense that your training loss is bigger (not all neurons are available for feed forward due to dropout for example).

But what is clear is that your model is not being optimized for your validation set, (almost a flat line). This can be due to many things:

- Your validation set is badly representative of your dataset, has a very easy predictions or very small.
- decrease learning rate or add more regularization (recurrent_regularization since you are using CuDNNGRU)
- Your loss function is not appropriate for the problem you are trying to solve.

Hope these tips help you out.

Comment: thank you for the help @Coderji. this is a time series model, and the loss function is 'mse'. to my knowledge this is supposed to be a rather appropriate loss function for time series predicition models. please tell me if you think otherwise

Comment: Yes, it is a approperiate for this case.. Therefore, I would suggest that you look into your validation set, is give a bigger set, shuffle your data or prepare a more representative validation set and supply it to `validation_data` parameter

Comment: the way i have done that is just add the `validation_data` parameter inside the `model.fit` method and the value is 0.33. but i haven't defined any `x_test` or `y_test`. i have only created the training arrays (`x_train` and `y_train`).